# Path Provider Using and Asset Problems

Tags: flutter

I want to add an image that I added to my application from the phone's gallery to the list and call it with Image.asset as a String value.

I managed to get the image with ImagePicker. Unfortunately, there is no next. I don't know exactly how to do this.

In short: I will select an image from gallery with ImagePicker and replace it with "Image.file"
I will do it by converting it to String value with Image.asset.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use image.file or image.memory to load an image from ImagePicker.

image.asset is for images that already exist within your app.

Comment: So do you have any advice? Important for my application. I've been dealing with the same problem for 2 days. :D